# Creating a bash file with variables with PHP and phpseclib

Tags: php, bash, variables, cat, phpseclib

I need to create a bash file with PHP using the phpseclib library.
This is the code I am using now:

```
   $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
screen -dmS $1 java -Xincgc -Xmx200M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7.jar nogui
        ");
```

The code works, and the file saves, but it skips the "$1". instead, it makes a file with two spaces between -dmS and java.

How can I make it so the $1 is written to the bash file?

Thanks

EDIT

This is the whole function:

```
    {
        $sPath = "minecraft/servers/".$user."/";
        $sSavingCode = "start.sh";
        $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
screen -dmS $1 java -Xincgc -Xmx200M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7.jar nogui
        ");
    }
```

$sPath and $sSavingCode are PHP variables, and the $1 is a bash variable that needs to be in the script.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the variable? `\$1`

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that, but it still leaves the 2 spaces

Comment: I have tried escaping, making the $1 into a variable like $foo = '$1', and everything I have tried or tried to find has not worked.

Comment: Can you show more code? Where do you get `$1` from?

Comment: I have added the whole function. The $1 needs to be in the bash file as a bash variable, and the $sPath and $sSavingCode are PHP variables

Comment: OK. I see your point. Anyway there.is no way bash gets.$1 with this expression. $1 is fed through function calling

Comment: So there is no way I can create a bash file with PHP that has a $1 in it?

Comment: From @Shal answer I see it was possible. In fact it is strange that it is working this way and not by changing your code to `\$1` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not assigning your command to a simple variable?

```
    $command = ' screen -dmS \$1 java -Xincgc -Xmx200M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7.jar nogui'

    $ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
$command
        ");
```

Comment: I'm assuming $sPath and $sSavingCode were declared in your PHP script, weren't they? Besides, is $1 actually supposed to be a shell variable?

Could you please give a try to the snippet added to my original answer?

Comment: That code did not work, it creates the file, but does not print any text in it

Comment: Are you willing to obtain the first argument passed to your script using $1? 

If so, please consider using native PHP global variable $argv as shown in my updated codeblock.

Comment: I tried your code, and it creates the file still, but does not print any text to it. I also tried `$ssh->exec("cat > $sPath$sSavingCode <<EOF
screen -dmS ".$argv[1]." java -Xincgc -Xmx200M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.7.jar nogui
  ");` and that still left 2 spaces

Comment: I remove the first one which might be misleading then. Thanks.